# Re-generating assets for Flame Game with Very Good Ventures template

Tags: flutter, flame

So I'm building a Flame Game, and I found [this template](https://verygood.ventures/blog/generate-a-game-with-our-new-template) (the actual code that comes with the template is [here](https://github.com/VeryGoodOpenSource/very_good_flame_game/tree/main/src/very_good_flame_game)) made by Very Good Ventures (it's the one used in the [Pinball](https://github.com/flutter/pinball) project made for Google I/O).

I'm just writing my code, and added my assets in the `assets/` folder, so far I only need images so I deleted all the other assets that came with the template and the unnecessary folders. Thing is, I don't know how to re-generate the `gen/assets.gen.dart` file to reflect the changes I've made to the `assets/` directory. I've tried running my app but I obviously get an error because the assets I'm trying to load are not defined.

I tried to look up what command is needed to regenerate the assets file, and most solutions I found included [this](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/forget-the-pain-of-assets-flutter-91414b9741aa#:%7E:text=Step%201%3A%20Add%20flutter_gen%20in%20pubspec.yaml) line of code which requires the `build_runner`, `flutter_gen` and `flutter_gen_runner` dependencies.

Now, I don't mind adding new libraries if necessary, but if they are needed, shouldn't those be in the `pubspec.yaml` of the template to begin with? I even checked the Pinball project repo to see if they had to add those dependencies and their `pubspec.yaml` does not include any of the runners or `flutter_gen`.

Anyway, I still tried adding the libraries and running the command `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`, which manages to regenerate the `assets.gen.dart` file to include my images and delete unnecessary directories but I still get an error.

When I do

```dart
loadSprite(Assets.images.ramp.path);
```

(just like they do in the VGV template), I get a red screen error because apparently `Assets.images.ramp.path` gets evaluated to `assets/images/assets/images/ramp.png` (there's an extra `assets/images/`).

After checking the `assets.gen.dart` file it seems like the VGV template creates the class `AssetGenImage extends AssetImage` while the `flutter packages ...` command creates an `AssetGenImage` that **doesn't** extend `AssetImage`.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here, because both the VGV template and the I/O pinball project manage to regenerate the assets files without issue. I just don't really know what I'm supposed to be doing.

(just in case, I have not changed anything else in the `pubspec.yaml` apart from removing the lines that pointed to the other assets directories I didn't need like `assets/audio/` and adding the 3 new dependencies)

Comment: Do you have all the assets in your pubspec file? The extra `assets/images` is usually a red herring.

Comment: @spydon in my pubspec i have `assets: -assets/images/`, which is the only folder i need because i only have images

Answer (score 2):

so you are probably getting this error because Flame by default adds a the `assets/images/` prefix path on its image loading code.

That is why on your error, you are seeing that part duplicated.

To properly use flutter gen, which generates the full path of the assets, you can simply "clear that prefix", which you can do just by doing so on your game class, you can do this as the first line of your `onLoad` method

```dart
images.prefix = '';
```